# VBA Formatting cells based on multiple conditions VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to VBA. Currently, I have 2 worksheets whose data will be updated automatically using the data inputted from the main worksheet. What I would like to do now is to format the cells to be of a certain color depending on the status I have selected for each row on the main sheet. I will illustrate the process in the pictures below:

1. This is the main page
   [image]
2. This is one of the 2 worksheets whose data displayed is linked to the main page.
   [image]

What I want to do is this. For each row on the main page, I can change the status of the row to be either  "Pending" or "Completed". When the status is changed on the main page, I would want to see the corresponding assignment name be updated to be red/green depending on the status on the worksheet.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: Do you just want to give the Text a color or the whole cell? If you color the whole cell it could be missleading in cases where you have 2 or more assignments in one day.

Comment: To format specific text in a cell you can use the cell's `Characters()` collection.

Comment: @snenson  I only want to give the text a color. I will give Tim's suggestion a try. Thanks!